# Ahhhhh! Where did the subform go?

Tags: forms, ms-access-2003, subform, adp

I have a form called Group in my MS Access ADP. On it is a tab control, and in each of the tabs there is a subform. The first tab contains the subform Users, and it isn't showing up in form view. Subform Users shows up in design view.

Any clue as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Just passed by to upvote for your question title. Made me laugh :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is an incorrect SQL statement as a record-source for the form.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the subform control is in front of the tab control, not behind it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you, you have a tab control with each tab having a subform. One of these subforms does not show up in Form View, but in Design view, correct?

Everything shows up in Design View, so it is normal that you see the subform there. It can have various reasons you are not seeing the subform in form view though:

- Please check if the subform control is on top (or on the tab control) of the tab control
- Make sure you set visible = true in the subform Users properties
- Make sure that DisplayWhen = "Always" or "Screen" and not "Print"

(Also take care that you set these properties for the subform in question and nothing else, it can sometimes be a hassle working with tab controls. You can check that you are working on the correct properties by looking on the selector drop down above the properties)

Comment: Checked all the points that you mentioned, and all the settings are correct.

Comment: Can you edit your original post and provide some screenshots? It is odd that your subform is not showing up at all. Try including another subform instead of the "Users" subform on that particular tab. Make it a simple subform e.g. just containing some test-text.